# Swift 4 : Set local notification once

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, uilocalnotification

I want to set a local notification for a specific time, but I have concerns about it. For example, when I set the local notification for once and I say that I scheduled it and suddenly the user's phone turns off, what's gonna happen? I'm sure this notification data is just available in the memory and it will disappear when the user's phone turns off.

And I know every time I set the same date, I am gonna get more notifications at that time. I just want one notification, but as I told you, I don't know how to handle the possibilities for the user.

Here is my sample code :

```
func scheduleNotification(inSeconds : TimeInterval, completion : @escaping (_ Success : Bool) -> ()){
    let notif = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    notif.title = "New notification"
    notif.subtitle = "Cool!"
    notif.body = "I liked it!!!!"

    let notifTrigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: inSeconds, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "myNotification", content:  notif, trigger: notifTrigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { (error) in
        if error != nil{
            print(error!)
            completion(false)
        }else{
            completion(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To make it clear, you only want the notification to be shown once? Also, if your phone is off I believe you will never get the notification. That's to make sure that if you turn it off for a while, you won't get bombarded with notifications for that time.

Comment: I mean I want to set one or two notifications just one time and after I open the app, I don't want to set again and again. And I know I can't do anything if the phone is off. I am just saying the possibilities and I'm trying to find what I can do about those problems.

Answer (score 1):

Local Notifications are stored between sessions. I just tested it by setting one and then switching my phone off and on. The notification still appeared. Of course you won’t get the notification if your phone is off.